# Mass Action needs to change the place Magento 2

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4, massaction

I have created the custom grid with **UI Component** and it's working good except the position of **Mass Action**.

For this I have written below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_grid_grid.custom_grid_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_grid_grid.custom_grid_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_grid_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="custom_grid_grid_data_source" >
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_grid_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="custom_grid/index/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Logger</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="custom_grid_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="message">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Message</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="type_of_message">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Type of Request</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="level_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Message Level</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Created at</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn class="ABCSolutions\Helloworld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomGridActions" name="actions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

After Login to Admin Panel the Grid Shows as below

[image]

I am not specified the position of **Mass Action** in the grid.

Can you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Worked after fallowing steps:

1. Please comment all columns except of selectionsColumn(in uicomponent)
2. Reload your admingrid first. So You'll get only checkbox column.
3. Now uncomment all columns & reload the page and your problem will be solved
4. Step 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="module/controller/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
         </massaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Go to **ui_bookmark**  table and delete your **custom_grid_grid** which is show into **namespace** column.

```
DELETE FROM `ui_bookmark` WHERE `namespace`="custom_grid_grid"
```

***After clear and flush magento  cache***